# Is there any way out of the infinite corridor?

Tags: dream

I started playing Dream and I thought I had solved all the puzzles (of the current version) until I stumbled across the portal located in one of the cave in the desert. I played through the colored mazes  (greatly reminding the Antichamber atmosphere) and I finally found myself walking through an infinite corridor with text written on the wall at the end. Unfortunately every step I take drive this text away. There are colored rooms appearing randomly on the right and the left of the corridor as you walk past through it. As you know all these room always lead you back to the corridor.

I figured out this might be some sort of maze where you have to enter in the right colored room in a specific order in order to reach the end of the corridor, however everything i have tested so far hasn't worked.

Is there any way to reach the end ?

Comment: Which game is Dream? Which platform?

Comment: @SysDragon On PC, it's available on Steam

Comment: Kinda a long shot since I haven't played the game, but, in Antichamber fashion, have you tried walking backwards?

Comment: @Humungus oh yeah, I've tried so many thing in this damned corridor :D